# Why does Openstack Swift services put all its data/files in root and not my specified partition?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I deployed using kolla-ansible 5.0.0.

I used fdisk to create a new xfs sda4 primary partition with size of 1.7 TB and then I created the rings following this documentation for kolla-ansible:

https://github.com/openstack/kolla-ansible/blob/master/doc/source/reference/swift-guide.rst

After I deployed, swift seems to work fine. However /dev/sda4 is not mounted to /srv/node/sda4 and all of swift's files or data gets put in root.

output of fdisk -l showing my sda4 disk partition I want swift to use:

```
[root@openstackstorage1 swift]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1999.8 GB, 1999844147200 bytes, 3905945600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000c22f6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          718848     2815999     1048576   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3         2816000   209663999   103424000   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda4       209664000  3905945599  1848140800   83  Linux
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.
```

output of df -h

```
Filesystem                                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootvg01-lv_root                    98G  3.4G   95G   4% /
devtmpfs                                       3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                          3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                          3.9G  9.0M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                                          3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/openstackvg01-lv_openstackstorage  2.8T   75G  2.7T   3% /var/lib/docker
/dev/sda1                                      347M  183M  165M  53% /boot
tmpfs                                          782M     0  782M   0% /run/user/0
```

this output of `df -h /srv/node/sda4` shows a logical volume of root disk is mounted on  /srv/node/sda4.

```
[root@openstackstorage1 swift]# df -h /srv/node/sda4/
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootvg01-lv_root   98G  3.4G   95G   4% /
```

but shouldn't my `/dev/sda4` partition I made be mount to `/srv/node/sda4` ?

Not sure what I did wrong and need guidance please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this was not working is cause my /dev/sda4 was not an xfs filesystem......I just had to run `mkfs.xfs –f –I size=1024 –L sda4 /dev/sda4` on my partition I created and then I mount it myself `mount -t xfs -L sda4 /srv/node/sda4`

I then had to restart all swift services and now all swift files and data are being stored in /srv/node/sda4 where /dev/sda4 is mounted.